# What is the 'Page Curl' Transition effect in PowerPoint VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, slideshow

.SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect = ??
The property is either a number or a string. I can't figure out how to get the Page Curl transition effect.
Anyone?

Thank you!

I've tried .SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect=ppPageCurl but that didn't work

Comment: Here is the MS enumeration page for EntryEffects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppentryeffect The correct syntax would be _ppEffectPageCurl_, but I don't see that on the page. It may not have been added to the VBA object model.

Comment: Thanks for your reply John. Yes I've seen that page too, and as you also noticed it was not added, probably the Page Curl effect is fairly 'new'>
Thanks again!

Comment: Once again, MSdocs for the fail, I guess.  In the VBA IDE, press F2 and search for ppEffect. I'm seeing four relevant entries:  ppEffectPageCurlSingleLeft, ppEffectPageCurlSingleRight, then the same two with Double instead of Single. 3946, 3947, 3948, 3949 respectively.  I used one or two of these with your code and it worked in PPT 2021.

Comment: Thanks for that search tip Steve! I'm quite new to VBA so I'm learning here. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `EntryEffect` is always a Number. Powerpoint VBA defines a long list of values as [Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.ppentryeffect), however it looks as this is not complete. I am not very familiar with all the effects, maybe some of those fancy effects where added lately and they either didn't update the enumeration or the documentation for that. Also, it seems not all values defined for the slideshow EntryEffect are allowed (I got a runtime error when trying to use some of the values).

However, that doesn't matter, you can assign the numbers directly. So you can write

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
    .SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect = ppEffectStripsDownLeft
End With
```

Or you can do

```
    .SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect = 2563
```

`ppEffectStripsDownLeft` is simply a Name (a Constant) for the value `2563`. How do I know? Goto to the VBA editor, open the immediate window (Ctrl+G) and type

```
 ? ppEffectStripsDownLeft
   2563
```

So all you have to do now is to figure out the correct numbers, and that's easy. Assign the effect you want to any slide (I did it for slide 2 in my example). Then switch back to VBA and enter in the immediate window

```
? ActivePresentation.Slides(2).SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect
```

Turns out that *Page Curl* gives 3948. Other examples are *Peel Off* = 3944, *Crush* = 3943 or *Airplane* = 3951 (and so on)

Now you can use

```
With ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
    .SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect = 3948
End With
```

and your done. Or, to make it clean, define the missing effects you are interested in as your own constants (or course you can name those effect constants whatever you like, only the number is important)

```
Const ppEffectCurl = 3948
Const ppEffectPeelOff = 3944
Const ppEffectCrush = 3943
Const ppEffectAirplane = 3951

With ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
    .SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect = ppEffectCurl 
End With
```

Comment: That's Brilliant! Thank you so much for your detailed answer! Took me ages trying all kinds of numbers from lists. Love the '? ActivePresentation.Slides(2).SlideShowTransition.EntryEffect' I'm quite new to VBA and didn't know that about the immediate window.
Again, thank you for replying!

Comment: See my suggestion above re the Object Browser (F2 in the VBA IDE).